# leave-one-out cross validation with knn in R

Tags: r, loops, machine-learning, cross-validation, knn

I have defined my training and test sets as follows:

```
colon_samp <-sample(62,40)
colon_train <- colon_data[colon_samp,]
colon_test <- colon_data[-colon_samp,]
```

And the KNN function:

```
knn_colon <- knn(train = colon_train[1:12533], test = colon_test[1:12533], cl = colon_train$class, k=2)
```

Here is my LOOCV loop for KNN:

```
newColon_train <- data.frame(colon_train, id=1:nrow(colon_train))
id <- unique(newColon_train$id)

loo_colonKNN <- NULL
for(i in id){
  knn_colon <- knn(train = newColon_train[newColon_train$id!=i,], test = newColon_train[newColon_train$id==i,],cl = newColon_train[newColon_train$id!=i,]$Y)
  loo_colonKNN[[i]] <- knn_colon
 }
print(loo_colonKNN)
```

When I print `loo_colonKNN`it gives me 40 predictions (i.e. the 40 train set predictions), however, I would like it to give me the 62 predictions (all of my n samples in the original dataset). How might I go about doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: as a side note, would it not be best to choose an odd number as for `k` so that it will never be undecided.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply call the `knn` function again, using a different `test` parameter:

```
[...]
knn_colon2 <- knn(train = newColon_train[newColon_train$id!=i,], 
                  test = newColon_test[newColon_test$id==i,],
                  cl = newColon_train[newColon_train$id!=i,]$Y)
```

This is caused by KNN being an non-parametric, instance based model: the data itself is the model, hence "training" is just holding the data for "later" prediction and does not require any computationally intensive model fitting procedure. Consequently it is unproblematic to call the training procedure multiple times to apply it to multiple test sets.

But be aware that the idea of CV is to only evaluate on the left partition each time, so looking at *all* samples is probably not what you want to do. And, instead of coding this yourself, you might be better off using e.g. the [`knn.cv`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/class/html/knn.cv.html) function or the caret framework instead, which provides APIs for [partitioning, resampling, etc.](http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html) all in one, therefore is pretty convenient in such tasks.